# How to remove an option from an exposed filter with a drop-down list?

Tags: views

This is this drop-down list for the field `field_gender` on the view whose name is `members`:

- M|Male
- F|Female

I know the following callback is executed (tested with var_dump...), but it doesn't do what I think it should do: **Provide only the option which value is "M" for "Male"** (this choice is decided programmatically, Views UI won't work).

Here is the callback:

```
/**
* Implementation of hook_views_pre_...().
*/
// function mymodule_views_pre_render(&$view){
// function mymodule_views_pre_build(&$view){
function mymodule_views_pre_execute(&$view){
    if ($view->name == 'members') {

        // get our filters
        $filters = $view->display_handler->get_option('filters');

        // Force
        $filters['field_gender_value']['value'] = array('M' => 'M');

        // apply changes
        $view->display_handler->override_option('filters', $filters);
    }    
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You use hook_form_alter:

```
/**
 * Implementation of hook_form_alter().
 */
  function mymodule_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
  switch ($form_id) {
  case 'views_exposed_form':
    // Force
    $form['field_gender_value']['#options'] = array('M' => 'M');
    break;
  }
}
```

Comment: It is amazing how this answer was down-voted, when the OP then answered saying they used this hook.

Comment: This Hook works in Drupal 8 too. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

If it is a select field, the time you will be adding it as expose filter you will get option to narrow down your options. Check the screenshot

[image]

Comment: Actually this won't work for, I need to do it programmatically (depending on using gender)

Answer (score 0):

Although I prefer using Views API I went with hook_form_alter. This is how I did it.

```
/**
 * Implementation of hook_form_alter()
 */
function mymodule_form_alter(&$form,$form_state,$form_id) {

    switch ($form_id) {
        /*
            ...
        */
        case 'views_exposed_form':
            if($form['#id'] === 'views-exposed-form-members-page'){

                // Get the user gender
                global $user;
                $user = user_load($user->uid);
                $user_gender = $user->field_gender[LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['value']; 

                // Get available exposed options
                $exposed_options = $form['field_gender_value']['#options'];

                // Override options by whitelisting only the user gender 
                $form['field_gender_value']['#options'] = array_intersect_key($exposed_options, array_flip(array ($user_gender)));

            }
    }
}
```